# Showing a set with operations comprise a non-ordered field

Tags: field-theory

Given set $S = \{0,1\}$, and operations $+$ and $*$ given by the following identities:

$$0+0=1+1=0;1+0=0+1=1;0*0=1*0=0*1=0;1*1=1.$$

I am trying to show $(S,+,*)$ is a field but not an ordered field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: The field axioms can be checked one at a time, a little tedious but not long.

To check it cannot be made into an ordered field, note that either $0\lt 1$, which leads to a contradiction, or $1\lt 0$ which leads to a contradiction.